# How to run statement under cursor in SQL developer tool?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

could you pls help in running a particular query in sql developer without selecting that query

for example in sql developer page i have three queries as below

```
select * from employees

select * from dept

select first_name from employees
```

If i press ctrl+enter all the queries will run. 
If i want to run the middle query (select * from dept), i need to select that particular  query then do ctrl+enter, this is something not quiet user friendly. 
i want to run that query just by keeping the cursor over that query (just like we do in TOAD).

is that possible in sql developer ? if yes pls help

thanks and regards,
Arun Thomas

Comment: Hope F5 will do the job in your case.

Comment: Maybe properly delimiting the statements using `;` would help? I don't know if SQL Developer actually uses an empty line instead of the standard `;` as a statement delimiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in sql developer, queries must be delimited with a ; this should allow you to execute the specific statement you have the cursor on. It's also worth noting that executing a script will always fire off all queries.